# Issues with my website copyright footer

Tags: html

Not really code related but website related which in a different view is programming. The copyright footer on a website has to be of current year, right!?!

Comment: @priya_singh 2 lines in the Question, still to lazy to read it ;)

Comment: A quick google search would quickly answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! But It uses PHP not HTML Actually. it uses the following code:
*

```
         $date=Date('Y');
         if($date==2016){
        echo 2016;
        }else{
            echo "2016-".$date;
        }
         ?>*
```

If you are not talking about this, Please me know.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to do this in PHP. The OP didn't clarify the language. I have done this javascript before.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to update the year date on copyright only if you make any change on your site.